# how debug sass in intellij file watcher. Cannot find output window

Tags: intellij-idea, sass, file-watcher

Im stuck at sass debug. I use Intellij Idea and file watcher to compile compile the scss files.
The problem is i cannot debug the sass files easily because i dont see the compilation output.

i write ***@debug 'some message'*** and ***@warn "some m."*** and expect it's gonna be shown during the build.

Only  error messages are shown (if they are found).

[image]

Expect to see some messages like above

ps:
I thought and looked for any setting such as clear console output on rebuild, but havent found.
Suppose it should be somewhere at file watcher settings.

The file watched successfully set to compile the scss to css.

Answer (score 6):

I found the filewatcher output settings location, look at below:

[image]

I wrote a warning message 'what a' so
The output and its location may be seen beneath

[image]